# When item of collection is changed

Tags: backbone.js

When a item of collection changed, collections "change" trigger is fired or not? If not should i bind them myself? Do anybody give me an example about this?

Answer (score 6):

the `change` event is fired every time a model's attributes are changed. this event fires for the model itself and for any collection the model belongs to.

```
someCollection.bind("change", function(model, attributes){
  // do something with the model, here
});
```

Comment: when i  someCollection.fetch(), function that you give will work i am right?